# Google API Key: iOS Restriction not working

Tags: ios, flutter, google-api

I am using Google Geocoding API, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json, from my iOS application to find the current city the device is currently in, using latitude and longitude.

I've created my API Key with restriction for iOS Apps. But when I call the api I got this error message

**This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address , with empty referer.**

However, if I set the restriction to none (Which I don't want this), the api works just fine.

I don't know if I missed something. I've double checked my bundle id. I really need help.

I was expecting the api would work if I set the restriction to iOS App